# Create association between 2 existing tables using sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have 2 existing ( User and PaymentPlan) tables that were created without associations between them.

PaymentPlan.ts

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "./DBConnections/SequelizeNewConnection";

export class PaymentPlan extends Model{
  public ID: number;
  public months: number;
  public fees: number;
  public name: string;
  
  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}

PaymentPlan.init(
  {
    ID: {
      type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    months: { type: DataTypes.NUMBER },
    name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  },
  {
    tableName: "paymentplans",
    sequelize,
  },
);
```

User.ts

```
import { PaymentPlan } from "./PaymentPlan";
import { Model, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "./DBConnections/SequelizeNewConnection";
    export class User extends Model{
      public ID: number;
      public name: string;
      public amount: number;
      public fees: number;
      public paymentPlan: number;
        
      public readonly createdAt!: Date;
      public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
    
    }
        User.init(
          {
            ID: {
              type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
              primaryKey: true,
              allowNull: false,
              autoIncrement: true,
            },
            name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
            amount: { type: DataTypes.NUMBER },
            fees: { type: DataTypes.NUMBER },
            paymentPlan: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
          },
          {
            tableName: "users",
            sequelize,
          },
        );
```

I wanted to add a one-to-many relation between these 2 tables so I added to User.ts

```
PaymentPlan.hasMany(User, {
  foreignKey: 'paymentPlan'
});
User.belongsTo(PaymentPlan);
```

and I ran the query

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT users_FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (paymentPlan) REFERENCES paymentplans(ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

that all is done to link paymentPlan column in User table with PaymentPlan table.
now when I run for example

```
await Users.findAll()
```

then the query being executed is

```
SELECT `ID`, `name`, `amount`, `fees`, `paymentPlan`,`createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `PaymentPlanID `FROM `users` AS `User`;
```

which ofcourse throws error:

```
[SequelizeDatabaseError]: Unknown column 'PaymentPlanID' in 'field list'
```

because I didn't create PaymentPlanID column. I specified the foreign key column to be paymentPlan.
what am I doing wrong? how to force sequelize to to set the foreign key column to 'paymentPlan' instead of creating column 'PaymentPlanID'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indicate the same foreign key in `belongsTo` as you already did in `hasMany`:

```
PaymentPlan.hasMany(User, {
  foreignKey: 'paymentPlan'
});
User.belongsTo(PaymentPlan, {
  foreignKey: 'paymentPlan'
});
```